# Were there any Greek Mythology heroes born of Goddesses?

Tags: mythology, greek-myth, eugenics

A typical Greek hero origin story was being born to a mortal woman and an Olympic god (usually, though not exclusively, Zeus the Philanderer). See Herakles, Perseus, Bellerophon, etc...

Were there **any** heroes in Classical Greek Myth (a single example will suffice) that were the reverse, i.e. born to an Olympic goddess from a mortal human father? I couldn't find any in my Googling, and my Mythology textbooks are long gone.

Comment: The Olympians had access to birth control. The Greeks didn't.

Comment: How is this not off-topic?   "Fantasy" doesn't include "classical mythology".   I suggest CLOSE

Comment: There's a Mythology.SE nowadays ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mythology and not science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - I'm pretty sure mythology was consiered in-scope

Comment: The latest meta seems to be [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6838/70236), which deems mythology off-topic unless related to SFF. It's and off-shoot of [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1053/70236), where religious works are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are very few examples, one of which is [Aeneas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeneas):

> a Trojan **hero**, the son of the prince Anchises and the goddess Aphrodite.

The Wikipedia article on [demigods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demigod) gives a good cultural explanation as to *why* there were not many:

> The fact that male deities of Greek myth had far more notable children with mortals than the female goddesses **can be attributable to the Greek male-dominated society being reflected in their religion**. Zeus, primarily, and also Poseidon, both had a multitude of affairs with mortal women, with Zeus having to shield them from his wife Hera after she was alerted to the infidelity. **The females were expected to remain loyal to their husbands, while the males were almost expected to take multiple lovers**, meaning that far more of the demigods in Greek myths were born on earth to human mothers than on Olympus to divine mothers.

Comment: Yeah, the latter was why I was kind of assuming there would be none. Excellent answer.

Comment: Leave it to [Aecheans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achaeans_(Homer))/Mycenians to make a "lower-status" demigod hero be a Trojan one :)

Comment: Achilles was also born of an immortal mother as was Orpheus.

Comment: @terdon - Good point. But strictly speaking, Thetis (Achilles' mother) wasn't an Olympian but a nymph/lesser goddess. Ditto Orpheus - mother was a muse (Calliope), not an Olympian goddess.

Comment: Never said they were, note the coy "immortals" in my original comment.

Comment: I would not call Virgil "classical" Greek mythology because he lived around 70 - 0 BCE and was Roman, while someone more 'canon' like Homer was working around the 8th century BCE. Virgil was basically writing Greek fanfiction.

Comment: Aeneas appears as Aphrodites' son in the Iliad as well; Virgil didn't invent that aspect of the character.

Answer (score 8):

Demi-gods and heros were often "city gods" -- the rulers of a given city-state would claim descent from the gods by way of a specific hero. Heroes born to Olympian mothers would be raised in Olympus, and not available to rule Greek city-states. Only mortal mothers are useful to establishing the "divine right of kings."

Comment: That is fascinating....where did you hear that?

Comment: +1 for "*yeah, that makes sense*" but -1 for no references.

Comment: Gah. "City gods" being used to provide divine heritage I learned in a seminar on Greek religion over 15 years ago. I have no idea what the reference was, or even what the textbook was. The use of mortal mothers over Olympian mothers is a straightforward extrapolation.